# MySQL query to increment of 10.000 the values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to increment every value of a column in my table of +10.000

For example, at the moment I have a column like that:

hits

- 12
- 1443
- 876
- 345
- 34
- and so on...

I would increase every value + 10.000
so it becomes

- 10.012
- 11.443
- and so on...

What's the correct SQL query I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple Googling can give you answer to this question.Anyway You can use [Update](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm) query to achieve above scenario.Like

```
Update yourtable set yourcolumn=yourcolumn + 10000 where somecondition
```

And if you are learning Mysql ,you can use [Mysql Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/) for further References

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = your_column + 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Before add you need to divide your column value like `(1443/1000)+10.000` this :-

```
Update yourtable set yourcolumn=(yourcolumn/1000)+10.000
where somecondition
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/34227)

Comment: I believe that the "." in the example is meant to separate the thousands, and it is not a decimal point - I know, it's annoying, but at least in some European countries we use "." for thousands, and "," for decimals. So Pi would be "3,14" and one million would be "1.000.000".